# How to connect to MSSQL Server using C++ (preferably without ant 3rd party API)

Tags: c++, sql-server

I want to connect to MSSQL server using C++. I am fluent with C# and I have been able to achieve that with C# without any issue but with C++ I get an error

> SQL Error: 0000009B238FF670 (SQLState: 0000009B238FF660, NativeError: 0)

Here is the code that I am using to connect to SQL Server. Server and db name are provided as input in console by the user

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include "DatabaseCheck.h"
#include <sqlext.h>
#include "Logger.h" // My internal classes
#include "Converters.h" // My internal classes
#include "LogTypeEnum.h" // My internal classes


void show_error(SQLHANDLE handle, SQLSMALLINT handle_type)
{
    SQLWCHAR sqlstate[6];
    SQLINTEGER native_error;
    SQLWCHAR msg[SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
    SQLSMALLINT msg_length;

    SQLGetDiagRec(handle_type, handle, 1, sqlstate, &native_error, msg, sizeof(msg), &msg_length);
    
    std::cerr << "SQL Error: " << msg << " (SQLState: " << sqlstate << ", NativeError: " << native_error << ")" << std::endl;
}

void DatabaseCheck::ConnectToDatabase()
{
    Logger logger;
    std::cout << "Please provide data server name: ";
    std::string dataServer;
    std::cin >> dataServer;

    std::cout << "Please provide database name: ";
    std::string databaseName;
    std::cin >> databaseName;

    std::string connectionString = "Data Source=" + dataServer +
        ";Initial Catalog=" + databaseName +
        ";Integrated Security=True;";

    try
    {
        // Initialize ODBC environment
        SQLHENV henv;
        SQLHDBC hdbc;
        SQLRETURN retcode;

        retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &henv);
        if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(retcode)) 
        {
            logger.LogToFile("Error allocating environment handle.", LogTypeEnum::Error);
            return;
        }

        retcode = SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
        if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(retcode)) 
        {
            logger.LogToFile("Error setting ODBC version.", LogTypeEnum::Error);
            SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv);
            return;
        }

        retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc);
        if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(retcode)) 
        {
            logger.LogToFile("Error allocating connection handle.", LogTypeEnum::Error);
            SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv);
            return;
        }

        // Connection string
        std::string connectionString = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=" + dataServer +
            ";DATABASE=" + databaseName + ";Trusted_Connection=yes;";

        // Connect to the database
        retcode = SQLDriverConnect(hdbc, NULL, (SQLWCHAR*)connectionString.c_str(), SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);

        switch (retcode)
        {
        case SQL_SUCCESS:
            logger.LogToFile("Successfully connected to SQL Server");
            break;
        case SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO:
            logger.LogToFile("Successfully connected to SQL Server");
            break;
        case SQL_INVALID_HANDLE:
            logger.LogToFile("Could not connect to SQL Server because of invalid handle", LogTypeEnum::Error);
        case SQL_ERROR:
            logger.LogToFile("Could not connect to SQL Server", LogTypeEnum::Error);
        default:
            logger.LogToFile("Failed to connect to the database", LogTypeEnum::Error);

            // Error handling
            SQLWCHAR sqlstate[6];
            SQLINTEGER native_error;
            SQLWCHAR msg[SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
            SQLSMALLINT msg_length;

            SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc, 1, sqlstate, &native_error, msg, sizeof(msg), &msg_length);

            /*std::string error = "SQL Error: " + converters.SQLWCHARToString(*msg) +
                " (SQLState: " + converters.SQLWCHARToString(*sqlstate) +
                ", NativeError: " + std::to_string(native_error);
            logger.LogToFile(error, LogTypeEnum::Error);*/
            std::cerr << "SQL Error: " << msg << " (SQLState: " << sqlstate << ", NativeError: " << native_error << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        // Disconnect and free handles in case of an error
        SQLDisconnect(hdbc);
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc);
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) 
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I am also aware of SQLAPI that can achieve this maybe easily but I believe its not free to use for commercial purpose.

Just for reference my C# code that works is:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DatabaseChecker
{
    public static class DatabaseCheck
    {
        public static void ConnectToDatabase()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please provide data server name");
                var dataServer = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Please provide database name");
                var databaseName = Console.ReadLine();
                var connectionString =
                    $"Data Source={dataServer};Initial Catalog={databaseName};Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
                using var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                con.Open();
                con.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Database is accessible");
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Database is not accessible");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Database is not accessible");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your C# code relevant or helpful?

Comment: You should probably get the real error message, right now it looks to be printing some pointer addresses

Comment: Native error being 0 would lead me to think there is no error...

Comment: @DaleK I thought when posting this question that adding the code I already know would maybe help to convey my intent if I am not doing it right in C++. Maybe that would help the community to understand my question/purpose better.

Comment: Your C# code does not add anything to the question. Anyway, start by printing the SQL diagnostics variables using **w**cerr, which knows how to print WCHAR types.

Comment: Or use the converters line that you commented out..

Comment: @Botje When I printed the error, this is what I am getting "SQL Error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Comment: `(SQLWCHAR*)connectionString.c_str()` is a bug. `c_str` produces a `char*`, not `WCHAR*`.

Comment: in that case I specified the connection string itself as SQLWCHAR* and it makes no difference, I still get the error.
SQLWCHAR* connStr = (SQLWCHAR*)"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=MYSERVER\\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=MYDB;Trusted_Connection=yes;";

Converters converters;
// Connect to the database
retcode = SQLDriverConnect(hdbc, NULL, connStr, SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);

Comment: You're gonna need a proper 3rd party open-source binding for DB. Otherwise, the sql API you end up with will be a C binding - which is in no terms intuitive for someone with a C# background. Beware of what you wish. Search for the proper open-source for C++. There's is no API for DB in C++23 STL.

Comment: `(SQLWCHAR*)"DRIVER` isn't it supposed to be: `(SQLWCHAR*)L"DRIVER`. My c++ is a bit rusty.

Comment: Btw, you will have more luck with the following connection string i think: `std::string connectionString = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER="+ dataServer +";DATABASE=" + databaseName + ";Integrated Security=True;";`

Comment: @siggemannen thank you, Actually what you suggested worked, I had to start SQLWCHAR with L.
(SQLWCHAR*)L"DRIVER - this worked for me.
I want to mark your comment as the answer but I see no option.